# Blazor Azure BlobContainerClient fail

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-blob-storage

I use

```
private async Task UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) {

//...

BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri($"{url}?{key}"),
                    new BlobClientOptions 
                    {
                        Transport = new HttpClientTransport( new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan } ),
                        Retry = { NetworkTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan }
                    });

                if (!(await containerClient.ExistsAsync()))
                {
                    await containerClient.CreateAsync();
                }
```

and on await containerClient.ExistsAsync() fails and throws 'Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy.'

I cannot figure out the issue

I generated a new key with all the rights and it's expiration date is in a year

Comment: What’s the key in your code?

Comment: I created it from "Shared Access Signature" in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer 
in the pop-up window I select everything mark the date one year in advance "Expiry time" and click create

Comment: Can you share what the SAS token look like?

Comment: sv=2021-10-04&ss=****&srt=***&spr=https%2Chttp&st=2023-08-14T14%3A38%3A51Z&se=2024-06-30T14%3A38%3A00Z&sp=***********

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

You need to generate SAS Token or URL like below:

[image]

[image]

Then use the below code which worked for me:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

async Task RithUploadusingSas(Stream fs, string fileName, string SAST)
{
    string containerUri = "https://rith99.blob.core.windows.net/rithwik";   
    BlobContainerClient containerClient1 = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(containerUri + SAST));  
    if (await containerClient1.ExistsAsync())
    {
        BlobClient blobClient1 = containerClient1.GetBlobClient(fileName);

        await blobClient1.UploadAsync(fs, overwrite: true);
    }
}    
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Downloads\ñ.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    string SAST = "?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rw=2023-08-15T11:54:07Z&st=2023-08-15T03:54:07Z&spr=https&s%2BExxNE%3D";
    await RithUploadusingSas(fs, "rithfile.txt", SAST);
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

You need to allow all resources to access this and then generate SAS from Storage Account(to check container exists or not you need  SAS of Storage Account), not from inside container, it will work for you too as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it. I tried the solutions from the comments and also it didn't work.
I've sent the byte[] to an endpoint and saved it via an additional service.